# Transfer SOL without end user to approve

Tags: transfer, cpi, signing

My question is in the title, so my program can transfer SOL from a PDA to another user but the thing is, based on an event, I'd like to pay the winner, but the winner always has to approve (on the frontend) the transaction which is not user-friendly. The account is owned by my program, I tried it trough CPI but the winner still has to sign (to receive/claim) if he wins, the other way was without using CPI (try_borrow_mut...) but it still asks the user to sign but both methods work, does anyone have an alternative perhaps? I have thought about auto approve but I blieve that Phantom removed that functionality

CPI struct

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct PayFromPDA<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub puppet: Account<'info, LockAccount>, //escrow PDA
    pub puppet_program: Program<'info, DepositApp>,
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub destination: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    fee_acc: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: only used as a signing PDA
    #[account(mut, )]
    pub authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

    impl<'info> PayFromPDA<'info> {
        pub fn pay_ctx(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Payo<'info>> {
            let cpi_program = self.puppet_program.to_account_info();
            let cpi_accounts = Payo {
                room_account: self.puppet.to_account_info(), //PDA that we want to sign the transac
                winner: self.destination.to_account_info(), 
                fee_acc: self.fee_acc.to_account_info(),
                authority: self.authority.to_account_info()
            };
            CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts)
        }
    }
```

cpi function call

```
pub fn pay_winner(ctx: Context<PayFromPDA>, amount: u64, bump: u8, user:Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
    rps_project::cpi::payo(ctx.accounts.pay_ctx()
        .with_signer(&[&[
            b"room_master".as_ref(),
            user.as_ref(),
            &[bump],
        ]])
    , amount)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

payout struct

```
        #[derive(Accounts)]
        pub struct Payo<'info> {
            /// CHECK:
            #[account(mut)]
            pub room_account: Account<'info, LockAccount>,
            /// CHECK:
            #[account(mut)]
            pub winner: AccountInfo<'info>,
            /// CHECK:
            #[account(mut, constraint = FEE_WALLET == fee_acc.key.to_string())]
            pub fee_acc: AccountInfo<'info>,
            #[account(mut)]
            authority: Signer<'info>
        }
```

payout function

```
  //payout
  pub fn payo(ctx: Context<Payo>, amount:u64) -> Result<()>{
    let room_account = &mut ctx.accounts.room_account;
    let payout:f64 = amount as f64 * 0.96;
    let fee:f64 = amount as f64 * 0.04;

    //fees
    **room_account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= fee as u64;
    **ctx.accounts.fee_acc.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += fee as u64;

    //payout
    **room_account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= payout as u64;
    **ctx.accounts.winner.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += payout as u64;  
    Ok(())
}
```

update, call on frontend

```
const [roomPDA, roomBump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [utf8.encode("room_escrow_wallet"), user1.publicKey.toBuffer()],
  program.programId
);

   const [puppetMasterPDA, puppetMasterBump] = 
await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([utf8.encode("room_master"), user1.publicKey.toBuffer()], 
puppetMasterProgram.programId) 

  await program.methods.initRoomEscrow(roomBump)
    .accounts({
      authority: puppetMasterPDA,
      signer: user1.publicKey,
      roomAccount: roomPDA,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
    }).signers([user1])
    .rpc()


  await puppetMasterProgram.methods.payWinner(new BN(2*lampsToSend), puppetMasterBump, user1.publicKey)
    .accounts({
      puppet: roomPDA,
      puppetProgram: program.programId,
      destination: random.publicKey,
      feeAcc: fee_wallet,
      authority: puppetMasterPDA,
    }).rpc()
```

Comment: Hmm by that code, the only account that requires the signing authority is the `room_account`. Whos the signing authority of that account? I assume its a PDA? So the `winner` account doesn't need to sign for this. How is the `payo` instruction called?

Comment: its authority would be a PDA, which is generated trough `find_program_address()` so it would be a PDA owned by the system program and that payout function is trigerred at frontend by a `await roomMasterProgram.methods.payWinner()`, I updated with the code to I call it on the frontend

Comment: Ok, I think i misread your question. So the user has to approve because the fee for the transaction has to be paid

Comment: You could use a node wallet to pay the transaction fee and send the transaction. Which wont require the user to approve

Comment: Is there no other way than a node wallet? btw my authority field is set to isSigner: false for the master program and isSigner true for slave program, or is that how it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but an easier way would be to have say a game wallet into which u can transfer your SOL and then whenever there is a winner u can transfer the SOL directly from ur game wallet..this will solve ur issue where the sol will be transferred without user intervention..if u r using next.js
U can save the secret key of the game wallet in ur .env.local file and call this secret key in ur frontend and let it sign the transaction in this way ur end user's will not have any need to sign any transaction.